# JRE and android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i create an android application, i include some external jar and library , but the jar and library is not available in android sdk ,for that i include JRE system library , the error was cleared and build successfully , but at runtime its thrown error no class def found.

Whether is it possible to use JRE system library and java console application in android or not.

If it is not possible how can i use such file into my application.

Whether it is correct or not to import JRE system library in android application.

Anyone suggest some interesting  blog or answer for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it's possible to include Java libraries in Android applications. It's possible some particular libraries might cause problems. If you let us know (1) exactly what process you're using to include the library (steps in Eclipse) and (2) which library you're trying to include that might help someone advise further.

Answer (score 1):

You can't include JRE system library because it uses native stuff that android doesn't have plus you would have duplicating classes. If the library doesn't compile in android, you have to port it there or find someone who already done that.